# SSMS : Edit table rows while RLS policy is on

Tags: sql-server, ssms, multi-tenant

So i have Row Level Security Policy in place, and am using session context to define Tenant Id.

Using SSMS as GUI for editing rows, while policy is on, i cant see any rows unless i of course set the Tenants ID as a session variable (for ex : `exec sp_set_session_context @key=N'TenantId', @value=3`).

I would like to be able to set that variable for any new query or table rows editing window, so i don't have to execute forementioned `sp_set_session_context` every time i open new window.

Is there a way to set this variable so its applied for every new query window?

Comment: Add yourself to the security policy? If you need to remove RLS for every session you are working on, why do you have it on for you in the first place?

Comment: @dfundako I want to work with policy on, so i always see the data specific to the tenant i'm working on

Comment: @dfundako If you add this part "Add yourself to the security policy?" as an answer, i'll actually accept it, as it basically lead to me getting almost what i wanted.